# Rendering a d3 chart in two places makes it render twice in the first area?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am trying to display two seperate d3 pie charts on my webpage in two seperate mat-cards, but they display in the svg tag of the first d3 chart in my code.

My code:

```
<section class="three">
  <!-- Card 1 -->
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <mat-card class="child-card">
    <mat-card-content class="card-grid">
      <app-d3-donut class="card-grid-graph"></app-d3-donut>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
  <!-- Card 2 -->
  <mat-card class="child-card">
    <mat-card-content class="card-grid">
      <app-apex [type]="'type1'" class="card-grid-graph"></app-apex>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
  <!-- Card 3 -->
  <mat-card class="child-card">
    <mat-card-content class="card-grid">
      <app-d3-donut class="card-grid-graph"></app-d3-donut>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
</section>
```

Both my d3 charts as I have configured in my app-d3 component display in the first card like this;

[image: D3chart-rendering-issue]

Is this because I have configured my d3 chart wrong or some other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is definitely that you use `d3.select('svg')` or `d3.select('app-d3-donut')` in your custom component. [d3.select](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#selecting-elements) is a wrapper around `document.querySelector`, which matches the *first element it finds*.

You need to make sure that this is not the first SVG element as seen from the `document`, but the first element as seen from the custom component. That is - you need to make sure that each Angular component can only look at and modify its own inner HTML.

From [the source](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/main/src/select.js), `d3.select` also accepts HTML elements. So you should use [Angular's ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to get a the reference to the SVG element, and then pass that reference to `d3`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-d3-donut',
  template: `
    <svg #chartEl></svg>
  `
})
class AppD3DonutComponent {
  @ViewChild('chartEl') svgElement: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    d3.select(this.svgElement.nativeElement).append('g') // etc
  }
}
```

Comment: ```this.svg = this.d3.select('figure#donut')
```
my code in my d3 component, used a figure element in the html file with [id]='donut'. Using your solution works perfectly! Thank you!